# Change terminal output location?

Tags: linux, command-line

I like to SSH into my raspberry pi at home. I want to be able to write a command via SSH that outputs to the terminal that's open at home.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try tmux.  Once a session is created... you can attach to the session from multiple computers and detach from it keeping the shell active until you re-attach to it.

Answer (score 1):

[`wall`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wall) comes to mind

There's also [`talk`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/talk). I used `talk` to IM with girls at SDSU before IM existed...

If the terminal is in a sleep mode, you'll need to figure out how to wake up the terminal. Also, there are probably ways to send serial output to the `/dev/TTY` the at-home terminal is on.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to display things to another TTY, [`write`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/write) is your man. It's basically the same thing as `wall` and `talk`, except it doesn't require a user on the other end to take action or bother other persons connected on the same machine.

Use [`who`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/who) to find out which TTY to send your message to.

Answer (score 0):

I used gnuScreen for this. You install screen on the rasperry pi, ssh into the rasp and start a screen-session. After running your command you detach the session from your terminal and it will be running in background.

After loging in from your home-pc, you can just reattach to the screen session and see the output.

With gnuScreen you also prevent problems from disconnection per ssh, what would probably kill the ssh-session on the server in case of connection loss or so.

[gnu screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)